# A stranger told me he would give me a weekly allowance. Is that a scam?

Tags: banking, bank-account, scams, sugar-daddy

A stranger told me he would give me a weekly allowance if I gave him my bank name, account number and routing number. Is that a scam?

Comment: "He sent actual pictures of himself instead of something from the phone gallery" - How is this relevant?

Comment: Is this stranger a sugar daddy?

Comment: Of course it is a scam.

Comment: How do you know these were pictures of himself?

Comment: Sorry, this is on the way to being closed as a duplicate. It’s a scam. No one is sending money to strangers. But, when I do, it’s via a safe, one way method, such as gofundme or PayPal. Knowing your PayPal address allows a stranger to send you money. Asking for any bank information is the only red flag you need to walk away. Better yet, run away.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica To be fair, bank name, account number and routing number are standard requests for any EFT payment. However, this would be highly uncommon for a stranger wanting to send a weekly allowance.

Comment: @Eric - for direct debit payment of my taxes, water bill, etc. For an employer to give me a direct deposit of wages. When an internet friend had a baby, and said she opened a 529 acct, a few friends said “what’s your PayPal acct ID”? And safely sent a small gift. Just because acct number is used for legit purposes, doesn’t mean it’s request is not a string red flag.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a scam.  Not because of the information he's asking for, but because of the fact that it's a complete stranger offering to give you a "weekly allowance" for... what?  Nothing in return?  **Nobody just goes around giving money to strangers for no reason.**  Even official charities have a specific mandate to follow regarding where and how they spend the money they collect.

Sending you pics proves nothing, there are innumerable sources of pics online he could have pulled those from.  (You might want to try a reverse image search on one of them just to see what comes up, but please don't take that as any sort of cue to continue interacting with this person.)

Whatever his motives are, you don't want to be on the receiving end.  Don't waste your time asking him questions or trying to "figure it out" - just stop responding, block the number / email address, and move on.  Rest assured you dodged a bullet, even if you don't know the caliber.